# Visualize a Risky program

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

[Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky) is a new language of mine, which features an interesting form of tacit programming. In this challenge, you'll take a Risky program as input, and visualize the parsing.

No knowledge of Risky is needed for this challenge, but it's a pretty interesting language so I'd recommend trying it :p.

### Task

Risky's parsing is based purely on the length of the program. It follows three rules:

1. If the program consists of one operator, it is parsed as a nilad
2. If the program consists of an even number of operators, the first operator is parsed as a monad and the rest is parsed as its argument
3. Otherwise, the middle operator is parsed as a dyad, and both sides are parsed as arguments

This is recursive; the argument(s) to a monad or dyad are parsed as if they are their own programs.

This forms a tree of operators. For example, the program `-1+!2` would look roughly like this:

```
  +
 / \
-   !
|   |
1   2
```

Your task will be to represent this by offsetting the operators lower in the tree, showing the structure of the program. For example:

```
  +
-  !
 1  2
```

All of the operators stay in order, but are vertically offset in order to show the structure.

### Input

Input will consist of a string of operators. If you want, you can assume the input doesn't contain any invalid Risky operators, though it would not affect the parsing.

### Output

You can output a visualization of the program in one of four ways:

**Top-to-bottom:**

```
      +
-      [
   +      ?
 !  !   2  0
  1  }   ]  [
```

**Bottom-to-top:**

```
  1  }   ]  [
 !  !   2  0
   +      ?
-      [
      +
```

**Left-to-right:**

(Using a shorter program for the next two to save space)

```
   2
  ?
 +
   1
  [
!
```

**Right-to-left:**

```
   !
 [
1
  +
 ?
2
```

Both LTR are RTL can be flipped upside down if you prefer.

### Test cases

Note that the above examples can be used as more complicated test cases. For the top/bottom ones, `-!1+!}+[2]?0[` is the program shown. For the rest, it's `![1+?2`.

**Program:** `1`

```
1
```

**Program:** `-1`

```
-
 1
```

(Top-to-bottom)

**Program:** `1+1`

```
1 1
 +
```

(Bottom-to-top)

**Progam:** `-1+2`

```
  1
 +
  2
-
```

(Left-to-right)

**Program:** `!!!!!`

```
 !
!
  !
 !
!
```

(Right-to-left)

### Other

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer (in bytes) per language wins!

Comment: Left-to-right and right-to-left look weird (I feel like one of them is wrong).

Comment: Is left to right upside-down allowed? like putting a monad on the top left corner and having subtrees extend to the right

Comment: @Bubbler One is upside down relative to the other. I'll allow them upside down though (to answer \@hyper-neutrino's question).

Comment: I cannot understand the `!!!!!` example, `!` is a monad, but it does not have an argument, on which number does it operate?

Comment: @Wasif The top of the tree is on the right side, so it is a dyad with two sub-trees each containing a monad with one nilad under it. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUlDQ.png)

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 35 bytes

```
↑{⊃{0~⍨⍺-1-∊1⍵0⍵}/-⌽⍬⊂⍛,1↓⊤1+≢⍵}↑¨⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTflfraFZXalhqGOoramfqWOok2llqF1Rq28YbxRjqK1cUctV/aht4qPerWByxaEVuo@6mqs1HvXuAgvs0tQBEtpgjY/aJhhqA1XW6j/q2avxqKvpUe8aTR3DR22TH3UtAcp0LgJJEmUeUHVHF1CRAXnGgYyAGmkA1IJuGNAgsHGziTPNoA7Ihrvq0HpDIs0CGlJNiQFA/YdWPOpa9B9kELI5uoa6QHMQpugSZ0waMIIe9fYBTTq03hjkw76pwUHOQDLEwzP4f5qCuq6iobZirXa0Uay9QbQ6l66uLhdQVDHaUNveSB0A)

Takes a string and puts each command on its own line top to bottom, indenting from left to right.

### The algorithm

Given the length of the input `n`, the indentation pattern (the length of each line) looks like the following:

```
f(1) = [1]
f(2n + 2) = let prev = f(n) in [1] ++ (2+prev) ++ [2] ++ (2+prev)
f(2n + 1) = let prev = f(n) in (1+prev) ++ [1] ++ (1+prev)
```

If we add 1 to the input, the recursive formula becomes nicer (with adjusting the base case):

```
g(1) = []
g(2n + 1) = let prev = g(n) in [1] ++ (2+prev) ++ [2] ++ (2+prev)
g(2n) = let prev = g(n) in (1+prev) ++ [1] ++ (1+prev)
```

which means we can use single reduction on the binary representation to get the job done.

### The code

```
↑{⊃{0~⍨⍺-1-∊1⍵0⍵}/-⌽⍬⊂⍛,1↓⊤1+≢⍵}↑¨⊢  Input: s

⊤1+≢⍵    Binary representation of 1+n
⌽⍬⊂⍛,1↓  Remove leading 1, prepend an empty list, and reverse
-        Negate the bits (for golfing purposes)
⊃{...}/  Reduce from right to left... (⍵: prev list, ⍺: next bit)
  ∊1⍵0⍵    Shorthand for 1,⍵,0,⍵
  ⍺-1-     Add ⍺-1 (-1 if zero bit, -2 if one bit)
  0~⍨      Remove zero if present
           which gives -1,(⍵-2),-2,(⍵-2) for 1 bit and
           (⍵-1),-1,(⍵-1) for 0 bit

 {...}     Compute negative padded lengths
↑     ↑¨⊢  Pad each char on the left side and rectify
```

Comment: Very nice.  "which means we can use single reduction on the binary representation to get the job done" -- what was the insight that connected the formula to immediately knowing it was equivalent to a reduction on the binary number?

Comment: @Jonah A recursive formula is a left-to-right reduce in binary if both `f(2n)` and `f(2n+1)` recursively call `f(n)` once and nothing else. Thinking in the reverse direction, going from `f(n)` to `f(2n)` is appending a zero bit, and going to `f(2n+1)` is appending a one bit.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 67 bytes

```
g=:(0,1+$:@<:)`([:(,0,])1+$:@<.@-:)`0:@.(=&1+2&|)
f=:' '&,.#"1~1,.~g@#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYtBDsIgEEX3PQW0pgMBJsByIko8gBcgTUyM0LjxAsrVEW3izrf77@XfWyuBhNVO7SjuSV5EIqGtXuRmMJouLUUUYXbKz0855EDAYNY4ja46jbXEqZ1PyErAHgxWloiNxA4U83C7rg@Wu3aKe9gmmC/wi/zDv2h4v75U8svRJmhv)

This produces an upside-down left-to-right tree, which should be valid per the comments.  For example, `f '-1+!2'` produces:

```
 - 
  1
+  
 ! 
  2
```

### the idea

- First notice the numerical pattern in the number of space indents:

  ```
  1 -> 0            
  2 -> 0 1          
  3 -> 1 0 1        
  4 -> 0 2 1 2      
  5 -> 1 2 0 1 2    
  6 -> 0 2 3 1 2 3  
  7 -> 2 1 2 0 2 1 2
  ```
- Then notice that all the heavy lifting can be put into a recursive function that does nothing but implement the  function described by the above table, since it's easier to work with integers than strings.  This is `g`.
- Zip a space and the input like so:

  ```
   -
   1
   +
   !
   2
  ```
- Finally, use the output of `g` and J's copy verb `#` to expand the spaces of that zip as needed.

Comment: Upside-down left-to-right trees were ruled to be acceptable in the comments, so I think this is good :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 bytes

```
⁹ð:2ß‘},`j⁹ð’ß‘}⁹;ðḂ?Ị?
Lç0⁶ẋż¹Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R487DG6yMDs9/1DCjVichC8x/1DATIgDkWR/e8HBHk/3D3V32XD6Hlxs8atz2cFf30T2Hdkb@//9fKTEpOSU1LT0jMys7Jzcvv6CwqLiktKy8orJKCQA)

-2 bytes thanks to caird coinheringaahing

This uses essentially the same approach as Jonah, so upvote [their answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229611/68942) as well. I came up with this solution independently, but Jonah's answer helped me consolidate a similar idea (to generate the indent array and convert that to indentation), and although I pretty much knew how I wanted to do it already, it helped me see that it was the correct approach and how to go about it.

```
⁹ð:2ß‘},`j⁹ð’ß‘}⁹;ðḂ?Ị?   Helper Link (dyad); given x and y, return the length x indentation array with minimum indentation y
                     Ị?   If x is insignificant (abs(x) <= 1)
⁹                         Return just y
                   Ḃ?     Otherwise, if x is odd (x % 2)
 ð:2ß‘},`j⁹ð              Dyadic chain for odd case:
  :2                      - floor divide by 2
    ß‘}                   - recursively apply this function to floor(x / 2) and (y + 1)
       ,`                 - pair that result with itself (exploit symmetry)
         j⁹               - join on y
           ð’ß‘}⁹;ð       Otherwise, if x is even, then dyadic chain for even case:
            ’             - decrement x
             ß‘}          - apply this link to (x - 1) and (y + 1)
                ⁹;        - prepend y
Lç0⁶ẋż¹Y                  Main Link (monad)
L                         Length of the input
 ç0                       Apply the helper link to that (x) and 0 (y)
   ⁶ẋ                     Return a list of whitespace, each row having number of spaces equal to the indentation level
     ż                    Zip with / interleave
      ¹                   (identity is applied to the right argument of the above to prevent the 2,1 chain with `Y`)
       Y                  Join on newlines
```

Comment: 32 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R487DG6yMDs9/1DCjVichC8x/1DATIgDkWR/e8HBHk/3D3V32XD6Hlxs8atz2cFf30T2Hdkb@//9fKTEpOSU1LT0jMys7Jzcvv6CwqLiktKy8orJKCQA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

A port of [Jonah's J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229611/64121).

-1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

```
S¯¸λNÈi>0šë0N2÷₅>.ø]Igèú»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9vc2FiaWX//1PCr8K4zrtOw4hpPjDFocOrME4yw7figoU@LsO4XUlnw6jDusK7//8tMSshMg)

```python
S                     # split input into list of characters
 ¯¸                   # push [[]]
   λ          ]       # starting with a(0)=[], calculate a(n) for n=0,1,... according to:
    NÈi               #   if n is even:
       >              #     each value of a(n-1) incremented by 1
        0š            #     prepend a 0
      ë               #   else:
       0              #     push a 0
        N2÷           #     floor(n/2)
           ₅          #     a(floor(n/2))
            .ø        #     surround the 0 with a(floor(n/2))
               Ig     # push the length of the input()
                 è    # index into the infinite list of indentations
                  ú   # pad each character of the input with the right number of spaces
                   »  # join by newlines
```

Comment: You can replace the `õS` with `¯` for -1.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
ＦΦ↨⊕Ｌθ²κ≔⁺…⟦¹⟧ι⁺⊕ι⁺⁺υ⟦⁰⟧υυＥυ◧§θκι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYyxDoIwEEB3vwK2uyAJsDIYHExI0LAThgYOaKxF2mJc/PZaqwwOl1zevXfdxFQ3M2HtMKsATlwYUnBkmqCUnaIbSUM9VCRHM8GCuA8yN1fEoNCaj3JLarHqv4Q7zcPmQiMzBCm2P7Jul8SRFRH9x8@a72rFpYEzu3uL9RUNBgpTyp6esHw97orc2jhMo/AVNVl7SBobP8Qb) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Based on @Bubbler's answer, so prints downwards indenting from left to right.

```
ＦΦ↨⊕Ｌθ²κ
```

Take the length of the input plus 1, convert to binary, and loop over the bits after the first.

```
≔⁺…⟦¹⟧ι⁺⊕ι⁺⁺υ⟦⁰⟧υυ
```

Concatenate two copies of the current list (predefined to be the empty list) together with `[0]` in between, then add 1 more than the bit to all the elements, then concatenate `[1]` to the beginning of the list if the bit is `1`, and save that as the current list.

```
Ｅυ◧§θκι
```

Pad each element of the input according to the calculated indentation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 97 bytes

```hs
f x|n<-length x,odd n,(p,q:r)<-splitAt(n`div`2)x=g p++[q]:g r
f(x:y)=[x]:g y
f[]=[]
g=map(' ':).f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjBCoIwGADgu0/xJ4Eb0yCPwxHd69RxCAq6OZx/c66Y0LuvOn7f1G/zaG1KCuIHm8qOqMMEsXwOA2BJXLlyT5tqc9aEayDYDebd1TQKDY4xubZcg88UiXynQsY/90zJVsg202LpHSmg4PSk0tIbBAG/uoN7hUfwN4QjKMgP8swudZ6@)

Defines `f :: String -> [String]`. Upside-down left-to-right output.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 223 bytes

```javascript
f=(c,d=(s,x=0,y=0,u=s.substr.bind(s),l=s.length,h=l/2|0)=>l==1?{[x]:y}:l%2==0?{[x]:y,...d(u(1),x+1,y+1)}:{[x+h]:y,...d(u(0,h),x,++y),...d(u(++h),x+h,y)},r=d(c))=>Object.entries(r).map(k=>" ".repeat(k[1])+c[k[0]]).join("\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NToQwFEZfxTQxuTe9UykrM@aOj@ADIAsoneGnFtKWCUR5dsREExff4pyz@PrqXkUTuimd7s/7fmUw1DBEWjij9djMUcW5jimouvMNRCR3KGf9LbXUsnvKvzLki2PWr5/FUp7X7ewec@bsF0kp1cAMGmmRmlapcTsfSbb/YkbtkUnKFf@UlD9KtrTiRoEbMHj8vNW9NUlZn0JnIwRUH9UEA1/Eg1DBTrZKMBS6RGmKocjKElU/dh7Euxe4m9HH0VnlxhtcQZy0zAXiy/4N)

---

Maps the input source into a lookup of token index and indentation amount, then transforms it into a proper string in the inverted left-to-right format.

Indented:

```javascript
f = (
    c,
    // Helper method that calculates the indentation.
    d = (s, x = 0, y = 0, u = s.substr.bind(s), l = s.length, h = l / 2 | 0) =>
        l == 1
            // Case 1: Nilad
            ? { [x]: y }
            : l % 2 == 0
                // Case 2: Monad + Arguments
                ? { [x]: y, ...d(u(1), x + 1, y + 1) }
                // Case 3: Dyad
                : {
                    [x + h]: y,
                    ...d(u(0, h), x, y + 1),
                    ...d(u(h + 1), x + h + 1, y + 1),
                },
    r = d(c)
) =>
    // We take advantage of the fact that the object entries are automatically sorted.
    Object.entries(r)
        .map((k) => " ".repeat(k[1]) + c[k[0]])
        .join("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>162</s> 157 bytes

```javascript
d=>(j=(r,b="")=>r.map(o=>o.map?j(o,b+" "):b+o).join`
`)((p=(r,x=r.length)=>x>1?x%2?[p(r.slice(0,z=x/2)),r[z|0],p(r.slice(z+1))]:[r[0],p(r.slice(1))]:[r])(d))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcvLCoMwEIXhfZ@iBAozJKbqqggTHyQIXtsarAlRJEjf3SoUSneH7/CbaqmmxvdujpbbdqetJQWGwIuaGENSXr4qB5aUPUZuwIqaszPDrOYWpbH9WJ5KBHBHFMjLoRsf83NPg0rycElz7cDLaeibDmKxUrimiMLr9R0X4netPEEsMu31H3@xQGgRN@f7cYY7sCjhKdvhAw)

**Explanation:**

Parses using recursion, and puts arguments into arrays. Then, it takes the result, and recursively indents anything in an array. Left-to-right, upside-down.